# How do I program AD5930 serially using SPI and the STM32 HAL Libraries?

Tags: c, embedded, stm32, spi, hal

I am working with an Analog Devices Waveform generator (AD5930) and am trying to program it using the spi peripheral on a STM32f767 Eval board. The waveform generator is to be programmed by loading data, in the form of 16bit words, into the devices registers using the serial clock of the SPI. The data words include register address, first 4 bits, and commands, the last twelve bits. Connections from the STM32 to the AD5930 are properly placed and when checking the lines with an oscilloscope I am can see the data, clock and control all come off the board. 
As of right now I'm trying to send 8 16bit command words using the HAL_SPI_Transmit command. Here is whats included in my **main.c**:

`

```
HAL_Init();
  SystemClock_Config();
  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_SPI1_Init();`

 `HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_4, GPIO_PIN_SET);
    HAL_Delay(5);  `

    spiData[0] = 0x0E83;
    spiData[1] = 0x13E8;
    spiData[2] = 0x2000;
    spiData[3] = 0x3800;
    spiData[4] = 0x63E8;
    spiData[5] = 0xC0C5;
    spiData[6] = 0xD002;
    spiData[7] = 0xA3E8;

    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_4, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
    if((HAL_SPI_Transmit(&hspi1,(uint8_t*)&spiData,8,5)) ==HAL_TIMEOUT){
            HAL_Delay(100);
        }
    while(HAL_SPI_GetState(&hspi1) != HAL_SPI_STATE_READY);
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_4, GPIO_PIN_SET);
    HAL_Delay(1);


        HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB, GPIO_PIN_8, GPIO_PIN_RESET);       
    HAL_Delay(1);
        HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB, GPIO_PIN_8, GPIO_PIN_SET);
        HAL_Delay(1);`
```

Below are my initialization specifications:

`

```
hspi1.Instance = SPI1;
  hspi1.Init.Mode = SPI_MODE_MASTER;
  hspi1.Init.Direction = SPI_DIRECTION_2LINES;
  hspi1.Init.DataSize = SPI_DATASIZE_16BIT;
  hspi1.Init.CLKPolarity = SPI_POLARITY_LOW;
  hspi1.Init.CLKPhase = SPI_PHASE_1EDGE;
  hspi1.Init.NSS = SPI_NSS_SOFT;
  hspi1.Init.BaudRatePrescaler = SPI_BAUDRATEPRESCALER_64;
  hspi1.Init.FirstBit = SPI_FIRSTBIT_MSB;
  hspi1.Init.TIMode = SPI_TIMODE_DISABLE;
  hspi1.Init.CRCCalculation = SPI_CRCCALCULATION_DISABLE;
  hspi1.Init.CRCPolynomial = 7;
  hspi1.Init.CRCLength = SPI_CRC_LENGTH_DATASIZE;
  hspi1.Init.NSSPMode = SPI_NSS_PULSE_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_SPI_Init(&hspi1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
  }
```

```
  RCC_OscInitTypeDef RCC_OscInitStruct;
  RCC_ClkInitTypeDef RCC_ClkInitStruct;


  __HAL_RCC_PWR_CLK_ENABLE();

  __HAL_PWR_VOLTAGESCALING_CONFIG(PWR_REGULATOR_VOLTAGE_SCALE3);

  RCC_OscInitStruct.OscillatorType = RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_HSI;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSIState = RCC_HSI_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSICalibrationValue = 16;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLState = RCC_PLL_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLSource = RCC_PLLSOURCE_HSI;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLM = 16;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLN = 192;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLP = RCC_PLLP_DIV2;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLQ = 2;
  if (HAL_RCC_OscConfig(&RCC_OscInitStruct) != HAL_OK)
  {
    _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
  }


  if (HAL_PWREx_EnableOverDrive() != HAL_OK)
  {
    _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
  }


  RCC_ClkInitStruct.ClockType = RCC_CLOCKTYPE_HCLK|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_SYSCLK
                              |RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK1|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK2;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.SYSCLKSource = RCC_SYSCLKSOURCE_PLLCLK;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.AHBCLKDivider = RCC_SYSCLK_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB1CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV2;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB2CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV1;

  if (HAL_RCC_ClockConfig(&RCC_ClkInitStruct, FLASH_LATENCY_3) != HAL_OK)
  {
    _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
  }

  HAL_SYSTICK_Config(HAL_RCC_GetHCLKFreq()/1000);

  HAL_SYSTICK_CLKSourceConfig(SYSTICK_CLKSOURCE_HCLK);


  HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(SysTick_IRQn, 0, 0);


GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_5;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_AF_PP;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_VERY_HIGH;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Alternate = GPIO_AF5_SPI1;
    HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStruct);

    GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_7;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_AF_PP;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_VERY_HIGH;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Alternate = GPIO_AF5_SPI1;
    HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOD, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = LD3_Pin|LD2_Pin|GPIO_PIN_8;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOB, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_4;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStruct);
```

Pin PB8 is used as a control trigger to begin waveform generation after registers are programmed, PIN PA5 is used for SPI Clock, PD7 as SPI data or MOSI, and pin PA4 is used as Chip Select.

What I observe on the oscilloscope(when viewing clock + data) is data being clocked in, what seems to be correct but hanging high when the clk has stopped. I dont get HAL TIMEOUT error so my assumption is the data was formatted correctly for transmission. When the program continues to run, and the trigger(Pin PB8) transitions I don't see a waveform in the output. What about my configuration may be preventing me from communicating correctly with the AD5930?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it can't be determined from outside it's a software of hardware error. Also one would require access to the **actual** hardware to tell. Debug your code and use a logic analyser coupled with code execution. Also getting rid of the HAL bloatware would simplify debugging greatly and massively decrease overhead. Finally check the datasheets/deference manuals of all devices.

Comment: @toohonestforthissite After checking the hardware, there was a loose connection causing some data loss.

Comment: So why do you accept an answer which is not related to the problem? Answer should only be accepted if they solve the **actual** problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`HAL_SPI_Transmit` third parameter is the number of bytes to transmit. Your data buffer contains 16 bytes (8 * sizeof(uint16) = 8 * 2 bytes), but you only send 8.